# Can Brightness of Windows changed per App?

Tags: windows, brightness

Is there any Software to customize Brightness for each app in Windows? is that possible with any software to do that?

Comment: Not a recommendation (I've never used any of these apps), but https://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/27/featured/window-opacity-software-for-windows-10.html talks about a few programs that tweek per window opacity - I posit that combining this with a dark/black background could get you some way towards the net effect you are asking about.

Comment: @davidgo: I am currently using one of those, but none of them can be customized per app

Answer (score 3):

No. Brightness and Contrast apply to the entire screen. What you want is not possible.

**Followup note:**  I tested inside several Virtual Machines and brightness controls were not available there either. The hardware also has the separate ability to change brightness outside the operating system.